# Given constrain $m=a_1>a_2>...>a_n$ and the elements are integer prove $\sum \frac{a_i-a_{i+1}}{a_i} < H_m$

Tags: number-theory, integers, harmonic-numbers

For decreasing positive integers $a_1>a_2>...>a_n>0$ when $a_1=m$.

Mark $a_{n+1}=0$,
Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_i-a_{i+1}}{a_i} < H_m=\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k}$

Might add that $n$ can be chosen by us, as long as $a_1=m$.

I got the problem from a different problem and if I prove this I solved the problem, so I'm not sure if it's true.

I know the harmonic number is achieved if we choose $a_i=m-i+1$ i.e  $a_m=1<a_{m-1}=2<...<a_1=m$

My attemp was to prove that the question is equivalent to proving
$$\min \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_{i+1}}{a_i} $$ is achieved by $a_i=m-i+1$ i.e  $a_m=1<a_{m-1}=2<...<a_1=m$.

Showing the equivalent is simple, but proving that this is the best  I havn't manage to do.

Comment: For $a_i-a_{i+1}=d$ you can write $(a_i-a_{i+1})/a_i=\sum_{j=1}^d1/a_i$. Try using this for each contribution on the left and then compare it to the right. Work with examples. Feel free to ask if you're stuck.

Comment: do you mean $a_i-a_{i+1}=d_i$?, im not sure how you got $(a_i-a_{i+1})/a_i=\sum_{j=1}^d 1/a_i$

Comment: As I said, work with examples. If $a_1=4$ and $a_2=1$, then $(a_1-a_2)/a_1=1/4+1/4+1/4$. Now look at a few examples for your $a_1,\dots,a_n$, use this trick and then compare it to $H_m$.

Comment: I get $\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{d_j}{a_j}$, I tried this approach with sadly no success.

Is there another trick I'm missing to compare it to $H_m$?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken is $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i-a_{i+1}}{a_i} =\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k}$ if $n=m$ and $a_i = m+1-i$, so the inequality may not be strict.

Comment: @Itsme: There seems to be a typo in your question, $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_i-a_{i+1}}{a_i}$ should probably be $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i-a_{i+1}}{a_i}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea has been nicely demonstrated in [Matija's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4881990/42969). Here is a formal proof for the general case.

For $1 \le i \le n$ and $a_{i+1}+1 < k \le a_i$ is $1/a_i \le 1/k$, so we have
$$
 \frac{a_i - a_{i+1}}{a_i} = \sum_{k=a_{i+1}+1}^{a_i} \frac 1{a_i} \le \sum_{k=a_{i+1}+1}^{a_i} \frac 1k \, ,
$$
with equality if $a_i - a_{i+1} = 1$, and strict inequality otherwise.

It follows that
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i - a_{i+1}}{a_i} \le \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=a_{i+1}+1}^{a_i} \frac 1k 
\overset{(*)}{=} \sum_{k=1}^m \frac 1k = H_m \, .
$$
$(*)$ holds because every integer $k$ between $1$ and $m$ is in exactly one half-open interval $(a_{i+1}, a_i]$.

Equality holds if $a_i - a_{i+1} = 1$ for all $i$, that is if $n = m$ and $a_i = m+1-i$ for $1 \le i \le m$. Otherwise the inequality is strict.

Answer (score 4):

A formal proof is a bit challenging to write and to read, so here's an example.
Say we have $a_1=8$, $a_2=5$ and $a_3=1$. This gives us $m=8$ and $n=3$. So, we consider the sum \begin{align*}S&=\sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{a_i-a_{i+1}}{a_i}\\&=\frac{8-5}8+\frac{5-1}5+\frac{1-0}1\\&=\frac38+\frac45+\frac11.\end{align*}
Now, we rewrite the fractions to obtain ones in the numerators, yielding
\begin{align*}S&=
\frac18+\frac18+\frac18+\frac15+\frac15+\frac15+\frac15+\frac11\\
&<\frac18+\frac17+\frac16+\frac15+\frac14+\frac13+\frac12+\frac11\\&=H_8.
\end{align*}
I hope this helps to establish the general case.

Comment: That demonstrates the idea nicely. For a formal proof of the general case you can write $$ \frac{a_i - a_{i+1}}{a_i} \le \sum_{k=a_{i+1}+1}^{a_i} \frac 1k $$ and then sum over $i$.